# Choosing weights for fitting autocorrelation functions

Tags: autocorrelation, fitting, weights

I wish to perform a Least Squares Fitting of time-autocorrelation functions. As confidence interval increase with time, initial times  should have greater weight in the fitting procedure. I wish to use [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) in order to fit the data.

*What is the proper way to set the weights?*

If it helps, I can calculate the confidence intervals as a function of time.